# Improve Data Transfer through socket from desktop to android service

Tags: java, android, sockets, bufferedreader, data-transfer

I'm kind of new to *Socket Programming*, I searched the web a lot and it just confusing me more.
So I want to transfer data from a desktop app which I wrote in Java, to my Android device.
Here's the logic:
I start a server socket from the app in my pc, I connect to this server from android.
In android, it connects and creates the socket in a Service and then in the service, there's a while loop that waits to receive a data.
when it receives a data, it shows a progress notification and gets the data.

**But there are problems here:**

1. Sometimes in my desktop app, it goes to the finally clause and shows transfer complete message. but data transfer is not over yet in my android device and then it suddenly stops transferring. this happens more when the file is large. but for small files it's ok **[FIXED with the help of @greenapps]**
2. when it starts receiving the file, android OS becomes SO slow that I can't do anything with my phone and LMK starts to kill processes again and again. even Launcher gets killed. I used a thread why this is happening? **[FIXED] I was calling updateProgressNotif() too often with every loop. I changed the code which if progress is more than 5%, update the progress bar. edited the code for others if they want to use codes**
3. Data transfer is slow. it took around 15-20 sec to transfer a 25MB data. I think it should be A LOT more faster? any way to improve speed?

And here's the code:

**CODE EDIT 1 :** I used suggestions of @greenapps and optimized my code. It sends the file completely ok now and the length of file before and after sending is exactly the same on desktop app and on android app file size before and after receive is same.

**CODE EDIT 2 :** I removed BufferedReaders because they were useless. I am already reading 64*1024 bytes so theres no need for BufferdReaders. Also, I used the suggestion of @greenapps and used readLine() for "name:size" encode.

**CODE EDIT 3 :** Added ability for the user to select more than one file and now the code knows how much should read from inputstream and won't read more than file size.

**Desktop App File Transfer Code:**
First it sends name and length of the file, then some pause with Thread.Sleep and then it sends the file. for example first it sends: **myfile.txt:3456**.
Because I need to know the name and length of the file to show the name of the file which I'm receiving in a notification. also the length for using it in a progress bar

```
public class SendFile extends Thread {
private Socket client = null;
private Main mainFrame;
private File[] files;
FileInputStream fis = null;

public SendFile(Socket client, Main main, File[] files){
    this.mainFrame = main;
    this.client = client;
    this.files = files;
}

public void run(){
    try {
        mainFrame.btnChooseFile.setEnabled(false);
        for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++){
            File file = files[i];
            String fileInfo = file.getName() + ":" + file.length() + "\n";
            client.getOutputStream().write(fileInfo.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, fileInfo.getBytes("UTF-8").length);
            client.getOutputStream().flush();
            Thread.sleep(200);
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[64*1024];
            int bytesRead;
            int current = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = fis.read(fileBuffer)) != -1) {
                current += bytesRead;
                client.getOutputStream().write(fileBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            client.getOutputStream().flush();
            fis.close();
            Thread.sleep(300);
        }
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        mainFrame.log("File Sent Successfully");
        mainFrame.btnChooseFile.setEnabled(true);
    }

} }
```

**Android App File Receiving Code:** this thread runs in a service. so when I send a file from desktop. it automatically shows a notification and starts receiving file even if the app is not open but android becomes SO slow

```
private class WaitForFile extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        FileOutputStream fos;
        BufferedReader in;
        String name;
        int fileSize;
        try {
            while(true) {
                String fileInfo;
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                fileInfo = in.readLine();
                name = fileInfo.split(":")[0];
                fileSize = Integer.parseInt(fileInfo.split(":")[1]);
                final String fileName = name;
                final int size = fileSize;
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        createGetNotification(fileName);
                    }
                });
                String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mydownloads/";
                File file = new File(PATH);
                file.mkdirs();
                File outputFile = new File(file, fileName);
                fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
                byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[64*1024];
                int bytesRead;
                int current = 0;
                float prevIncr = 0;
                int bytesToRead = Math.min(fileBuffer.length, size);
                while ((bytesRead = is.read(fileBuffer, 0, bytesToRead)) != -1) {
                    current += bytesRead;
                    fos.write(fileBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesToRead = Math.min(fileBuffer.length, size-current);
                    float incr = ((float)current/(float)size)*100;
                    if(incr - prevIncr > 5) {
                        final float increment = incr;
                        prevIncr = increment;
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                updateProgressNotif(increment);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    if(current == size)
                        break;
                }
                if(size == current) {
                    fos.flush();
                }else{
                    outputFile = null;
                }
                final File receivedFile = outputFile;
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        doneGetNotification(receivedFile);
                    }
                });

                fos.close();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        stopForeground(true);
                        disconnectedNotif();
                        stopSelf();
                    }
                });
        }
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `byte[] fileContent = new byte[(int) file.length()];` this will cause `OutOfMemoryException` when your file is larger application heap size

Comment: @mr.icetea I know this problem. I'll fix it later. I'm testing this with small files now. I need to fix the problems I wrote in my questions. not others. but thanks anyway

Comment: i wrote a comment not a answer ok.

Comment: Is the file transfered ok now? Is the file size the same? I can hardly believe that as the way you decode file name and size is no good.

Comment: In the server code you are not checking the return value of `bis.read()`. You should do that as you do in the client. Do away with that big buffer -as mr.iceta already said- and use the same code as in your client.

Comment: In the client you determine `int size`. But you are not comparing it to `int current`.

Comment: @greenapps I sent a 24mb music and it was ok. but I know this code needs lots of tweaking. so if you have any suggestion please help me out in optimizing the code. thank you

Comment: What is 24mb? milli bit?

Comment: @greenapps Thanks for the suggestions. I'll work on them
I meant 24megabyte file.

Comment: So you ment 24 MB.  Now you did not answer if size == final current == filesize before == filesize after. In the client code you have a comment that something stays in the buffer for the next time. This happens because you decode file name and size wrong. Why is fileInfo 48 bytes?

Comment: @greenapps I actually didn't test if the file size was exactly the same before sending and after receiving. I just checked if the .mp3 file was ok or not and it was ok.
My app becomes so slow and LMK kills lots of processes so I really can't test file sizes because most of the time my app gets killed by LMK in android and this is my first biggest problem here!
what do you mean by decoding file name? you mean the way I put file size and length together with ":" and get them by using split() in client?
P.S sorry, English is not my native language.

Comment: @greenapps I didn't know what size I should allocate to fileInfo so 48 is just a random number actually!

Comment: You put them together -the encoding on server side-. But the decoding -on client side- is completely wrong.  You read 48 bytes. And if that is more than the length of filename and size you throw away bytes of the file. You should really check filesize before and after. All starts with transfering every byte. What is LMK?

Comment: @greenapps It's "Low Memory Killer" in Android. I don't think it throws away bytes of the file because I flush it on server side and put the thread to sleep for 300 milliseconds. So when I read from the fileInfo buffer, it doesn't have any bytes of the file because still I didn't put file bytes in my OutputSteam. Am I correct or I'm missing sth?
Do you have any other suggestion to send the file name and length before sending the file bytes? I use filename and length to show a notification for the filename and progressbar on downloading the file.
Are there any better way than doing this?

Comment: That is very freaky code to trust on a sleep. There are better ways of course. I will help you to do that better. But before i do that i would like you to produce first decent code that checks the filesize. So as a start do not send filename and filesize. Take one file of which you/the client know(s) the name and size at start. Then let your server just send the file and the client just read it. Check the filesizes! If that code is ok we will continue sending name and size first.

Comment: @greenapps read my edited question. Lots of problems solved and only a few remains :)
I removed that [continue;] part. there is no bytes left in the buffer now so for the next while loop it does not read anything. it waits for my encoded (filename:filesize) input

Comment: @greenapps I also fixed the slowing problem. Any help on optimizing the code for better speed and more reliable would be appreciated.
Also, please post your answers in the answer section so I could tick your answer as the correct answer

Comment: `I made a change in server code that user can't send a new file before the previous file is finished.`. Wrong. Just send two files at one buttonclick of the user. That's what i suggested before.

Comment: No your code is not ok yet. Introduce an `int totalBytesRead`. Then compare with `size`. Then adapt `is.read(fileBuffer))`. Use  something like `is.read(fileBuffer,bytestoread))`. bytestoread will be the min(fileBuffer.length, size-totalBytesRead). If you dont adapt the amount of bytes to read then you will ask more ten size bytes as you do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the comments.

The transfer of file name and size and using a sleep() is no good. You now send for instance `myfile.txt:3456`. But you better send a line like `myfile.txt:3456\n` and remove the sleep(). Then in the client you use `readLine()` to read the line. Also the splitting with `getFileSize()` can be done better. You can do away with that function completely and only use Integer.valueOf().

Comment: Thanks for all your help. my apps seems a lot better now.

Comment: readLine() worked. now there's no need to make a byte[48] buffer. I just read it into a string. this was a great idea.
Also getFileSize() is no needed anymore. I used Integer.parseInt() instead

Comment: But still sleep() is needed. sometimes it causes some problems when I remove it. but if I use sleep() code works completely.

Comment: Then please show complete code. But before you do that solve the `constraint` ;-).

Comment: I edited my question. see "CODE EDIT 2"
I tested it with sending 2 files. first file received OK. but for the second one my app crashed in decoding fileName:size part. But I restricted my app to wait for a file to finish then allow another file to send.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of:

1. The `flush()` after sending the file info.
2. The `sleep()` after that.
3. The `exists()` and `delete()` calls.
4. The final `flush()` calls, replacing them with `close()` calls.
5. If possible, the progress monitor.

(1) to (4) accomplish nothing useful, and (5) can waste more time than it is telling you about.

Comment: Why I should remove flush? Isn't it for sending the data to socket? does write() do the work of flush?
For the (4), I don't want to close my socket. I want it to be open for the future data transfers

Comment: You should remove the flush because it reduces throughput, which is what you were asking about. If you don't want to close the socket, you should retain the flush, but you also need to properly constrain how much data you're reading, whuch you're not doing at all.

Comment: what do you mean by "constrain how much data you're reading"?
You mean, for example, I should put an appropriate size in respect of the file size for my byte[] instead of the fixed byte[64*1024] size?

Comment: He means that your client blindly tries to read more data from the stream then size bytes. What if the server sends two files right behind each other? The client would have consumed the following name and size already. Change the code in such a way that the client does not request more than size bytes pro file. Test with the server sending more files at once without pause or sleep.

Comment: @EPJ I fixed the "constrain" part :) see my code edit 2 thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problems by using `DataInputStream`

```
InputStream is = receive.getInputStream();
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
final String fileName = dis.readUTF();
final long size = dis.readLong();
...
```

And for sending side, use DataOutputStream

No need to use those Thread.Sleep() with DataStreams and it's a lot more reliable for sending files.